# NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest with ARC

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, automatic-ref-counting

I am beginning to play around with ARC, and one of the first experiements I was trying was to make an HTTP call to a URL and get back some data. Of course, the HTTP status code is important to me, so that means I went to my "goto" of using `sendSynchronousRequest` like:

```
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;

NSData *oResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:responseCode error:error];
```

With ARC enabled I get a compiler errors and warnings on that last line.

**Errors**:

> Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'NSURLResponse
>   *__autoreleasing *' is disallowed with ARC
>
> Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'NSError
>   *__autoreleasing *' is disallowed with ARC
>
> file://localhost/Users/jason/Projects/test/Data/DataService.m: error:
>   Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Implicit conversion of an
>   Objective-C pointer to 'NSURLResponse *__autoreleasing *' is
>   disallowed with ARC
>
> file://localhost/Users/jason/Projects/test/Data/DataService.m: error:
>   Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Implicit conversion of an
>   Objective-C pointer to 'NSError *__autoreleasing *' is disallowed with
>   ARC

**Warnings**:

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSHTTPURLResponse *_*strong' to
>   parameter of type 'NSURLResponse **_autoreleasing *'
>
> Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSError *_*strong' to parameter of
>   type 'NSError **_autoreleasing *'

From what I can tell the reference passing is what is messing this up, but I am unsure what the correct way to resolve this is. Is there a "better" way to accomplish a similar task with ARC?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;

  NSURLRequest *request;

  NSData *oResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];
```

you missing the reference to the error/responceCode pointer!

Comment: LOL... serves me to trying to think after the holidays!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the (NSHTTPURLResponse __autoreleasing *)type and (NSError __autoreleasing *)type.

```
NSHTTPURLResponse __autoreleasing *response = nil;
NSError __autoreleasing *error = nil;

// request
NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

And you can handle them in the follow:

```
if (response){
    // code to handle with the response
}
if (error){
    // code to handle with the error
}
```

Otherwise, you **cannot** use response and error as global vars. If did, they will not work correctly.Like following:

```
.h
NSHTTPURLResponse *__autoreleasing *response;
NSError *__autoreleasing *error;

.m
// request
NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:response error:error];
```

The code above **will not work!**